# Cancel functionality in a href

Tags: jquery

I have a link like

```
<a href="www.site.com"  class="cancel">go there </a>
```

And  then I have some jQuery:

```
$(".cancel").click(function(){
        confirm("sure??");
 });
```

But when I click cancel in the alert box it still goes to www.site.com in stead of doing nothing. How to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the return statement:

```
$(".cancel").click(function(){
    return confirm("sure??");
});
```

Comment: Usually this happens to me :-)

Answer (score 10):

returning bool is the old way to do it but is not the preferred method in every browser and I have had many problems with it these days. jQuery wraps the event object and handles  the event canceling for you.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

```
$(".cancel").click(function(event){
    if (!confirm("Sure??"))
       event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the bool from confirm() ?

(Not much of a jQuery wizz, though :) )

Answer (score 1):

Chad had it right.

event.preventDefault(); is the correct fix. I tried returning false for a click event on an anchor tag and it wouldn't work because I was calling window.location first. By setting event.Default() as the first line in my handler I could then create the window and it opened correctly without allowing the href to execute.