# How can I integrate javascript onclick function with php?

Tags: php, javascript

I am having a problem with onclick function integrating it with php .Can someone please help

Below is my codes

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="Javascript">
function delete()
{
    val del=confirm("Do you wanto delete the player?");
    if(del==true)
    {
        alert("player Deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("record not deleted");
    }
    return del;
}
</script>
</head>
<?php 
Echo “
<a href='delete.php?player_id=$player_id' onclick='delete()'>Delete</a>”
?>
```

Comment: @Lee Taylor edit is appreciated

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is your function not executed when klicking on the link?

Comment: @akluth yes it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty good solution. However, It adds a little extra to your code. I do not recommend using this method too much. I am a new PHP developer, so there are probably somethings this method can and cannot do.

also I cannot seem to prevent this method from loading a new page, so the best way is to add your php to the beginning of the file. This is also a better solution for using AJAX (my opinion)

if the current file is index.php...

make a form tag element

---

```
'<form action="index.php" method="post">'

'<input type="submit" name="helloWorld" value="hello World">'

'</form>'
```

---

here you will display the content of what you are trying for, with a click

---

```
'<article>'

    '<?php echo myFunction(); ?>'

'</article>'
```

---

this next php markup can go anywhere as long as it it is in the same file... Unless you know how to work around. Best place is before the HTML.

---

```
'<?php '
    'function myFunciton() {'
       'if (isset($_POST[helloWorld])) {'
          'echo "hello world"; ... your methods'
       '}'
     '}'
```

---

or you could directly access it without using a function

```
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
       <input type="submit" name="hello" value="hello">
       <input type="submit" name="goodBye" value="goodBye">
    </form>
    <article>
       <?php
           if (isset($_POST[hello])) {
               echo "This happens if you click hello";
           }
           if (isset($_POST[goodBye])) {
               echo "This happens if you click goodBye";
           }
        ?>
     </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

the most important thing: do not use the javascript keyword **delete** ([JavaScript delete operator help](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/delete.php)) as function name! Your function (and thus onclick) won't work because of this!
Change it to something appropriate like *deleteRecord* and you could use php only to output the ID, like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function deleteRecord()
            {
                if (confirm("Do you wanto delete the player?")) {
                    alert("player Deleted");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Record not deleted");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="delete.php?player_id=<?php echo $player_id ?>" onclick='deleteRecord();'>Delete record?</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

kind regards,
P.

Comment: This worked Like a charm so now how can I stop it from goin to the php page for delete ? It does everything but also it goes to the delete page wat I do not Like

Comment: it still deletes even if u cancel

Comment: You could use for example jQuery to prevent the link: import jQuery (for example directly from [google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)) and then use event.preventDefault() in the else part. More info about preventDefault can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785033/cancel-functionality-in-a-href). Example:
import jQuery: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
code modification:
                else {
                alert("Record not deleted");
  event.preventDefault();
                }

Comment: oK BUT THE SCHOOL REQUIREMENTS SAID JAVA SCRIPT STRICTLY

Comment: In this case use PHP more extensively and maybe change the complete flow and outlook of the page.