# Run PHP code with click on Button

Tags: php, onclick

I need to run php code when I click on btn.

my Html code:

```
<button type='button'>Run my PHP code</button>
```

my php code (run when click on btn) :

```
<?php
   echo "Click On YesBtn";
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I integrate javascript onclick function with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266704/how-can-i-integrate-javascript-onclick-function-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the button is in a .php page you can simply do:

```
<button type='button' onclick="document.write('<?php echo "Click On YesBtn"; ?>');>Run my PHP code</button>
```

if your php code is in a sepprate file you have to submit it with a GET/POST ect. request. Like so:

```
<form method="post" action="welcome.php" id="form1">       
    <button type="submit" form="form1" >Run my PHP code</button>
</form>
```

.
.
.

```
//welcome.php
<?php
   echo "Click On YesBtn";
?>
```

Comment: Using `document.write()` after the page is loaded will wipe out the page.

Comment: @Barmar That is true. It will, but there were no other tags in the example to write to so i assumed that was the desired outcome.

Comment: how Instead welcome.php i use from <?php ?> in html file?

Comment: @آهومحمدیان change the file extention of the document that has the button to a .php. So if you had the button in an **index.html** file then you would change it to **index.php** and its good to go.

Comment: What to write here action="?"
 I do not want to use welcome.php

Comment: @آهومحمدیان the action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. So you can send it to a function using something like action="somefunction()" if that function exists in or is linked to that page you are submitting the form to. Or action="myScript.php" to link to a page.

Comment: I need use from function f() in yourpage.php. now what to write action"?"

Comment: at the beginning of the page use `<?php require_once ( 'yourpage.php' );  `  then in your formuse `action="f()"`

Comment: What if both the php and html codes are in a single file and on clicking the button the php function gets called. Your answer has put the code inside the function inside the onclick() but that's not good idea to perform.

Answer (score 1):

The form has to have a type of "submit" in this case, then you can send the form data for processing to a PHP file of yours choice. The form data is sent with the HTTP POST OR GET method and also remember to set the form action. Below is a sample code.

```
<form method="post" action="welcome.php">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

//welcome.php
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   echo "Click On YesBtn";
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make your button a submit button for a form that calls a php page https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: why to do such a costly operation like submitting a form just for an onClick ??

Comment: @RohitasBehera the answer in the duplicate question you tagged is also a form submit.

Comment: I was just asking :( .... & no I dint votedown

Comment: how Instead welcome.php i use from <?php ?> in html file?

Comment: php is server side code, it has to be triggered from the server, not the browser.

Comment: What to write here action="?" . I do not want to use welcome.php . 
how Instead welcome.php i use from <?php ?> in html file?

Comment: Change your html file's extension to .php instead of .html and put that filename in the action ex: action="yourpage.php"

Comment: I need use from function f() in yourpage.php.

now what to write action"?"

Comment: The answer is on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328354/calling-a-particular-php-function-on-form-submit   Good Luck!